# Pycord embed make customizeable fields

Tags: python, for-loop, discord, discord.py, pycord

I want to make customizable fields in python with pycord. by that i mean a command with a customizable amount of fields for each field i want to make a customizable value and name so that for each field the content can be different in the embed. so far i wrote that bit of code:

```
async def daily(ctx, *fields: discord.Option(int)):
    d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{d1}", description="", color=discord.Color.dark_purple())
    for field in fields:
        

    embed.set_footer(text="", icon_url="")
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed)
```

but i don't really know what to do in the loop. by customizable i mean discord.Option also for the value and name for the fields. So for each field i want to enter a custom value and name through discord.Option

As i said i didnt do to much but i sat one it for atleast 3-4 hours and didnt came up with much.

Comment: Is this a slash command, or do you want to add parameters to your command?

Comment: @BlueRobinhere is what i meant how do i make a custom amount of fields via command and custom the value and name of them also vie command all in on

Comment: I believe you would have to do this manually.

Comment: u sure @BlueRobin ?

Comment: theres gotta be a way

Comment: I edited my question to answer that specifically

Answer (score 0):

To add parameters to a slash command, you need to do the following:

```
slash_command(ctx, parameter:discord.Option(int, "Name of parameter", required=False):
```

The first parameter of discord.Option is the type of the option. The next parameter is the name. Then you can set kwargs.

Automating this would be extremely difficult and ineffective. Even if you figured out how to automatically add parameters, you would have to constantly reload commands each time. This would be ineffective and wouldn’t be very scalable. An alternative to this would be adding as selector (with pycord’s built in discord.ui) to the message itself instead of as a command parameter.

Comment: i know this but how do  i make a custom amount of fields via command and custom the value and name of them also vie command all in one

Comment: To add multiple fields, you can just add another parameter to the command with different parameters in the discord.Option. @MaxMustermann